# How to convert empty to null in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `Employee`, it's empty, here is the information about the columns:

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM Employee;
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Id     | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Salary | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried to display the highest salary, if there's no highest salary(which is the case given that the table is empty for now), return null:

```
mysql> SELECT if (min(Salary) = max(Salary), null, min(Salary)) FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary;
+---------------------------------------------------+
| if (min(Salary) = max(Salary), null, min(Salary)) |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                                              NULL |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Great, it worked. Then I tried to display the second highest salary, if there's no second highest salary(which is the case given that the table is empty for now), return null:

```
mysql> SELECT if (min(Salary) = max(Salary), null, min(Salary)) FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT 1,1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

It returned `Empty set` instead of `NULL`, why? How to display NULL in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the `LIMIT` works after your `AGGREGATE` functions, you will have to use `subquery`. Can you try the following query:

```
SELECT if (min(Salary) = max(Salary), null, min(Salary)) 
    FROM (
        SELECT Salary
            FROM Employee 
            ORDER BY Salary DESC 
            LIMIT 1,1;
    ) T
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is in the limit clause.

Try using a `LIMIT 0, 1` instead. MySQL's limits are 0-indexed, meaning that your query is currently trying to obtain the second record, which doesn't exist.

Try:

```
SELECT
    IF (MIN(Salary) = MAX(Salary),
    null,
    MIN(Salary))
FROM Employee
ORDER BY Salary DESC
LIMIT 0,1;
```